# Get variable from a component to another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue app with 3 components, we'll talk about just 2 of them, "exchange" and "pair". My goal is to get a value from exchange and import it into pair. I have seen similar questions to mine here but the answer to them was use vuex or other similar technologies, I want to do this without vuex as I am new to vue and I want to keep everything simple. Below I have the code for my Exchange.vue

```
export default {
name: 'exchange',
data () {
  return {
    exchanges,
    selectedExchange,
    msg: 'Exchange',
    search: ''
  }
},
methods: {
 returnExchange(){
   return selectedExchange;
  }
 }
}
```

And here is my code for Pair.vue

```
import exchange from './Exchange';
export default {
name: 'pair',
components:{exchange},
data() {
  return {
    pairs,
    msg: 'Pair',
    selected: ''

  }
 },
}
```

If I try to use selectedExchange in Pair.vue it says it's undefined, how can I use that variable in Pair.vue?

Comment: You actually make it more complicated rather than simple if you want to do such stuff without Vuex. You can also use an EventBus: https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860

Comment: I've done it with $emit which to me seemed really simple, might try vuex in the near future

Comment: `$emit` sends an event to the parent, just one level up. What if your app grows big and you would need your component's data in it's great grandparent?

Comment: In my app it will never happen and I would emit the data from the parent to the grandparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the value as a `prop`, and with this example use the `.sync` modifier to update the values between components.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier